# MongoDB refuses connection to Node-RED

Tags: mongodb, node-red

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [1], but MongoDB is refusing connections, as error messages says:

"MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]"

Node-RED is running from a docker container, and MongoDB is on the host machine

MongoDB service is running properly, and when I type on browser "localhost:27017", appears "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port" message.

How to make, so, MongoDB accepts connections from NodeRED?

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5o4tIz2Zzc

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the MongoDB service is running properly? If you can't connect, that suggests that it isn't.

Comment: Yes, it is. I've verified via "htop" and "service", and in both cases it's shown that mongodb is running.

Comment: The mongodb server logs will probably tell you what's up; have you checked them yet?

Comment: Logs say nothing about it, it's like no connection were made.

Comment: Detail: Node-RED is running from a docker container, and MongoDB is on the host machine.

Comment: That is not just a detail, that is the heart of the entire problem! You can't connect to a host machine service, from within a container, using the address "localhost" because that is the address of the container, not the host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: That worked! I've set --net=host to docker container, and connections to MongoDB were possible. Thank you so much, Vince!